# Find a harmonic function in the cylindrical shell between $r=a$ and $r=b$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

> Calculate $\phi$, satisfying $\nabla^2 \phi=0$ between the two cylinders $r=a$, on which $\phi=0$, and $r=b>a$, on which $\phi=V$.

I calculate it and found the solution is $$\phi=\frac{V}{\log b-\log a}\log r-\frac{V}{\log b-\log a}\log a.$$However, I am not sure if it is right.

Actually, I am having trouble in determine its dimension. Is it $2$ or $3$ if I use the following formula:
$v(r)=b\log r +c$, when $n=2$; $v(r)=\frac{b}{r^{n-2}}$, when $n\ge3$?

But they all seem not right, since this is for a radially symmetric boundary condition. In this case, it is not radially symmetric.

Could someone kindly help me look at it? Thanks!

Comment: As mathifold.org said: originally you have a function in 3D (not radially symmetric), but since it does not depend on one of three variables, you're looking for a function in 2D (which is radially symmetric). The answer involves $\log r$ where $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the function is considered to be constant along one direction, then the function needs only to be harmonic in the other transverse directions. For instance if we are working in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and the cylinder extends in the $z$ direction, then we should look for some $\phi(x,y,z)=\phi(x,y)$ (that is, not really depending on $z$), and then $\nabla^2 \phi=\dfrac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial x^2}+\dfrac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial y^2}+\dfrac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial z^2}=\dfrac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial x^2}+\dfrac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial y^2}$. For this reason, we may think the problem as stated in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the solution you propose is right, although we get a 'cylindrical' function and not a 'spherical' one (if we should deal with spherical function, then we would take $n=3$).

I hope these remarks are useful.

Answer (score 0):

See section 6 of http://www.ewp.rpi.edu/hartford/~ernesto/F2004/IFEM/Notes/w03.pdf.  It's about as general as you can get for Laplace on a cylinder.